# How to remove node_modules and restore them in ionic 2 project

Tags: git, ionic2, node-modules

Ionic 2 source code of my project after removing platforms coming around 124MB. out of which `node_modules` occupying 98MB. So while checking in/out from git its eating more space.

Can I remove `node_modules` before checking in and restore them after checkout? is there way to do it? any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding/removing the `node_modules` folder when checking in/out from GIT (or any other folder or file) add a `.gitignore` file like [this one](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/.gitignore) in the project directory.

In that file, you can specify all the files and folders that should be ignored by GIT.

Please notice that the `node_modules` should not be included in the repository, because all the information needed to restore its content is stored in the `package.json` file. Because of that, if by any other reason you need to delete the `node_modules` folder, you can then restore them by running `npm install` (that command will install all the dependencies listed in your `package.json` file).